# Unity - How to Smooth Out Constant Velocity on Rigidbody2D

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, physics, velocity, smoothing

I am setting constant velocity for my character movement in my 2D game. However since using the method my character seems to be shaking a little. Is there a way to fix this and smooth the movement out?

Here is I set the velocity in the Update function:

```
constantVelocity = new Vector3 (playerInputX * speed, playerInputY * speed, 0);
```

I then apply this velocity to the the Rigidbody2D component in the FixedUpdate function.

Comment: Is the shaking due to you changing the velocity too abruptly?

Comment: I don't think so as it is at a constant pace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that my problem had nothing to do with the object I was moving but the camera that was following it. The camera was trying to Lerp towards the object in Update. I changed this to FixedUpdate and it now works perfectly.

Thanks for the help anyway,

Tommy

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do this.

1. You can always use `Time.fixedDeltaTime` to smoothen your player movement.
2. You can try low pass filtering on our constantVelocity.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried using Time.fixedDeltaTime but that didn't fix the problem. How do I use a low pass filter?

Comment: Ahh never mind I have worked it out now. I'll post how I did it.

Comment: Sure i would like to know

Comment: It is most probabily becase playerInputX and playerInputY values changes rapidly. Like going from 0 to 1 in a frame or so, if you smooth that out, then you got your answer.